# Windows Server 2008 & 8 Release Preview Error 0x0000225

Tags: windows, installation

I recently found a computer with the specs:

- AMD Sempron64 3200+ 1.8GHz
- DDR2 1GB @ 533MHz
- ASUS M2N MX motherboard
- Onboard GeForce 6100

I burned an image of Windows 8 RP 64 bit and booted it. I got the message Error code: 0x0000225

I tried looking up the code but all the results have to do with enabling IO APIC on Virtualbox, but I'm running this on a real physical computer. What can I do to install Windows 8 RP?

**UPDATE**: I tried installing a copy of Windows Server 2008 (Dreamspark) and I got the same error code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to enable this ambiguous option "ACPI APIC" in the bios, which is probably the equivalent of Virtualbox's "Enable IO APIC"